# Need to select column from subquery into main query

Tags: oracle, subquery

I have a query like below - table names etc. changed for keeping the actual data private

```
SELECT inv.*,TRUNC(sysdate)
FROM Invoice inv
WHERE (inv.carrier,inv.pro,inv.ndate) IN
(
    SELECT carrier,pro,n_dt FROM Order where TRUNC(Order.cr_dt) = TRUNC(sysdate)
)
```

I am selecting records from Invoice based on Order. i.e. all records from Invoice which are common with order records for today, based on those 3 columns...

Now I want to select Order_Num from Order in my select query as well.. so that I can use the whole thing to insert it into totally seperate table, let's say orderedInvoices.

```
insert into orderedInvoices(seq_no,..same columns as Inv...,Cr_dt)
(
    SELECT **Order.Order_Num**, inv.*,TRUNC(sysdate)
    FROM Invoice inv
    WHERE (inv.carrier,inv.pro,inv.ndate) IN
    (
        SELECT carrier,pro,n_dt FROM Order where TRUNC(Order.cr_dt) = TRUNC(sysdate)
    )
)
```

?? - how to do I select that Order_Num in main query for each records of that sub query?

p.s. I understand that trunc(cr_dt) will not use index on cr_dt (if a index is there..) but I couldn't select records unless I omit the time part of it..:(

Comment: `select...from invoice inner join order on (inv.carrier=o.carrier and inv.pro=o.pro and inv.ndate=o.n_date) where trunc(o.cr_dt)=trunc(sysdate)`?

Comment: Thanks @Passerby . I will use this one. Order table has duplicate records for combination of those 3 columns, lets hope this works for that scenario as well..

Comment: By The Way, if Orders table is not unique on those columns (because I am getting some duplicate records even though there are unique records in that table.. ) - how exactly I use distinct here ?.. . Probably I want to use ' group by inv.carrier,inv.pro,inv.ndate - but how to use this?

Comment: You don't need to ensure unique before you `join`; but if you really want to make unique, you can replace `order` with a subquery like `inner join (select ... from order group by carrier,pro,n_date) o where...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table `ORDER`<sup>1</sup> is unique on `CARRIER`, `PRO` and `N_DT` you can use a JOIN instead of IN to restrict your records, it'll also enable you to select whatever data you want from either table:

```
select order.order_num, inv.*, trunc(sysdate)
  from Invoice inv
  join order ord
    on inv.carrier = ord.carrier
   and inv.pro = ord.pro
   and inv.ndate = ord.n_dt
 where trunc(order.cr_dt) = trunc(sysdate)
```

If it's not unique then you have to use DISTINCT to deduplicate your record set.

Though using `TRUNC()` on `CR_DT` will not use an index on that column you can use a functional index on this if you do need an index.

```
create index i_order_trunc_cr_dt on order (trunc(cr_dt));
```

<sub>1. This is a really bad name for a table as it's a keyword, consider using `ORDERS` instead.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for answer, I had used table names for example purpose only, actualy tables names are different :). I think that 'Order' table will have duplicate rows for combination of 3 columns.. So I will use the query from previous comment. Hope it works..